# How to stop Zygote crashing, android tablet caught in boot loop

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, boot-loop

Using tablet as a front panel kiosk.  Was runnning fine for weeks. Now its stuck on the boot splash screen.  Seems zygote is crashing. This error in logcat repeats.  Any thoughts?

```
I/AudioFlinger(  471): Loaded primary audio interface from sunxi audio HW HAL (audio)
I/AudioFlinger(  471): Using 'sunxi audio HW HAL' (audio.primary) as the primary audio interface
I/CameraService(  471): CameraService started (pid=471)
E/CCameraConfig(  471): ------------------------device ID
E/CCameraConfig(  471): camera device id 0
E/CCameraConfig(  471): ------------------------device ID
E/CCameraConfig(  471): camera device id 0
I/AudioFlinger(  471): AudioFlinger's thread 0x14b22b8 ready to run
W/AudioFlinger(  471): Thread AudioOut_1 cannot connect to the power manager service
I/AudioPolicyService(  471): Loaded audio policy from LEGACY Audio Policy HAL (audio_policy)
D/AndroidRuntime(  504):
D/AndroidRuntime(  504): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit <<<<<<
D/AndroidRuntime(  504): CheckJNI is OFF
F/libc    (  504): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x40496765 (code=2)
I/DEBUG   (   82): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   (   82): Build fingerprint: 'softwinners/nuclear_evb/nuclear-evb:4.0.4/IMM76D/20130606:eng/test-keys'
I/DEBUG   (   82): pid: 504, tid: 504  >>> zygote <<<
I/DEBUG   (   82): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 40496765
I/DEBUG   (   82):  r0 01381754  r1 4053e220  r2 00000000  r3 44ef4040
I/DEBUG   (   82):  r4 01381754  r5 bef7bf94  r6 ffffffff  r7 404966e9
I/DEBUG   (   82):  r8 00000001  r9 bef7b9f8  10 00000000  fp bef7bfcc
I/DEBUG   (   82):  ip fffffef8  sp bef7b9e8  lr 404996c1  pc 40498eca  cpsr 40000030
I/DEBUG   (   82):  d0  44eb912844eb90b0  d1  44eb919844eb9192
I/DEBUG   (   82):  d2  44eb920844eb91eb  d3  44eb927844eb9244
I/DEBUG   (   82):  d4  44ef78d844ef78a0  d5  44ef794844ef7910
I/DEBUG   (   82):  d6  44ef79b844ef7980  d7  44ef7a2844ef79f0
I/DEBUG   (   82):  d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   82):  d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   82):  d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   82):  d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   82):  d16 0000000000000000  d17 3f50624dd2f1a9fc
I/DEBUG   (   82):  d18 41c83605ea000000  d19 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   82):  d20 0000000000000000  d21 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   82):  d22 0000000000000000  d23 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   82):  d24 0000000000000000  d25 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   82):  d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   82):  d28 0000000000000000  d29 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   82):  d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   82):  scr 60000010
I/DEBUG   (   82):
I/DEBUG   (   82):          #00  pc 0004ceca  /system/lib/libicuuc.so (_ZN6icu_4610UnicodeSet12applyPatternERNS_21RuleCharacterIteratorEPKNS_11SymbolTableERNS_13UnicodeStringEjR10UErrorCode)
I/DEBUG   (   82):          #01  pc 00075792  /system/lib/libdvm.so (_Z12dvmLinkClassP11ClassObject)
I/DEBUG   (   82):
I/DEBUG   (   82): code around pc:
I/DEBUG   (   82): 40498ea8 767ee5bb ccf4e215 2b3c6a21 57a69de5  ..~v....!j<+...W
I/DEBUG   (   82): 40498eb8 2ebada11 dd7f45f9 7575e71f d4faceca  .....E....uu....
I/DEBUG   (   82): 40498ec8 67fd9b3e b83d3fd5 86609cd0 e8e40229  >..g.?=...`.)...
I/DEBUG   (   82): 40498ed8 91e52e02 4e6fef92 55501d54 2de73e7d  ......oNT.PU}>.-
I/DEBUG   (   82): 40498ee8 f8429d51 38ef6cac 83245f41 4ccc3113  Q.B..l.8A_$..1.L
I/DEBUG   (   82):
I/DEBUG   (   82): code around lr:
I/DEBUG   (   82): 404996a0 9903ffcd 46334652 f7f04638 4620f901  ....RF3F8F.... F
I/DEBUG   (   82): 404996b0 46524639 f8cd464b 95018000 fc02f7ff  9FRFKF..........
I/DEBUG   (   82): 404996c0 28006828 4648dd03 fe22f001 9910e7d8  (h.(..HF..".....
I/DEBUG   (   82): 404996d0 f240b129 f2c00302 602b0301 4620e7f3  ).@.......+`.. F
I/DEBUG   (   82): 404996e0 f7fc4649 e7eeffa9 41f0e92d 4690b086  IF......-..A...F
I/DEBUG   (   82):
I/DEBUG   (   82): memory map around addr 40496765:
I/DEBUG   (   82): 40446000-4044c000 /system/lib/libicui18n.so
I/DEBUG   (   82): 4044c000-40538000 /system/lib/libicuuc.so
I/DEBUG   (   82): 40538000-40542000 /system/lib/libicuuc.so
I/DEBUG   (   82):
I/DEBUG   (   82): stack:
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7b9a8  00000001
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7b9ac  4088f795  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7b9b0  00000000
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7b9b4  00000001
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7b9b8  40a07018  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7b9bc  000000a0
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7b9c0  40a172b8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7b9c4  408ccf90  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7b9c8  0137cb5c  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7b9cc  40a172b8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7b9d0  01381090  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7b9d4  0137c7f0  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7b9d8  01381754  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7b9dc  bef7bf94  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7b9e0  df0027ad
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7b9e4  00000000
I/DEBUG   (   82): #00 bef7b9e8  00000001
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7b9ec  bef7bf94  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7b9f0  458996ae  /data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@core.jar@classes.dex
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7b9f4  bef7bca4  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7b9f8  4053eb50  /system/lib/libicuuc.so
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7b9fc  00000200
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7ba00  bef7bca4  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7ba04  400b6474
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7ba08  458996ae  /data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@core.jar@classes.dex
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7ba0c  40082a4d  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7ba10  0000004b
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7ba14  01401578  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7ba18  00000001
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7ba1c  bef7bca4  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7ba20  bef7ba58  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7ba24  00000000
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7ba28  00000000
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7ba2c  00000000
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7ba30  bef7ba58  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7ba34  bef7bf94  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7ba38  01381754  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7ba3c  bef7bca4  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7ba40  00000001
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7ba44  00000000
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7ba48  458996ae  /data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@core.jar@classes.dex
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7ba4c  4049973b  /system/lib/libicuuc.so
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7ba50  00000000
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7ba54  bef7bf94  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7ba58  4053e220  /system/lib/libicuuc.so
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7ba5c  00000000
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7ba60  ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7ba64  404966e9  /system/lib/libicuuc.so
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7ba68  01381754  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7ba6c  00000000
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7ba70  bef7bca4  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7ba74  bef7bf94  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7ba78  bef7bca4  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7ba7c  4049987d  /system/lib/libicuuc.so
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7ba80  bef7bf94  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7ba84  404b7d2b  /system/lib/libicuuc.so
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7ba88  01381378  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7ba8c  01381378  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7ba90  013813ac  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7ba94  0138154c  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7ba98  bef7bf94  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7ba9c  403c6e77  /system/lib/libicui18n.so
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7baa0  01386260  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7baa4  00000004
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7baa8  013810b8  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7baac  013810c8  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7bab0  000006e8
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7bab4  400b6474
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7bab8  013810c0  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7babc  00000014
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7bac0  44ef4040  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7bac4  400838b1  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7bac8  00000001
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7bacc  00000001
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7bad0  00000000
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7bad4  00000001
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7bad8  00000000
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7badc  00000014
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7bae0  44ef4040  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7bae4  40083f13  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7bae8  00000001
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7baec  4088f795  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   82): #01 bef7baf0  40a0f520  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7baf4  408ae99c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7baf8  40a07018  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7bafc  0137c7f0  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7bb00  408ccf90  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7bb04  bef7bb28  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7bb08  44ed6c40  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7bb0c  bef7bb6c  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7bb10  00000000
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7bb14  00000000
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7bb18  bef7bbf0  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7bb1c  4084e20c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7bb20  bef7bb2c  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7bb24  00000000
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7bb28  00000000
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7bb2c  00000000
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7bb30  00000000
I/DEBUG   (   82):     bef7bb34  00000000
I/ServiceManager(   79): service 'media.audio_policy' died
I/ServiceManager(   79): service 'media.audio_flinger' died
I/ServiceManager(   79): service 'media.player' died
I/ServiceManager(   79): service 'media.camera' died
I/Netd    (  506): Netd 1.0 starting
I/        (  505): ServiceManager: 0x1b9a958
I/AudioFlinger(  505): Loaded primary audio interface from sunxi audio HW HAL (audio)
I/AudioFlinger(  505): Using 'sunxi audio HW HAL' (audio.primary) as the primary audio interface
I/CameraService(  505): CameraService started (pid=505)
E/CCameraConfig(  505): ------------------------device ID
E/CCameraConfig(  505): camera device id 0
E/CCameraConfig(  505): ------------------------device ID
E/CCameraConfig(  505): camera device id 0
```

Comment: Reinstall the stock ROM and check again.

Comment: The Kiosk is setup remotely. I'd have to get the system shipped back here to do that.  This would be the last resort.

Comment: Review your modification history of the rom post-establishment to include new kernel builds and OS application upgrades/modifications/replacements. Identify the point in change history when the issue surfaced and "roll-back" to the point preceding that. You have also not posted enough of the correct portions of the logcat to determine the actual problem.

Comment: Continued- You can grep your logcat dump with the process id as your term. F/ = fatal error and process id is 504. Post that output as a pastebin on the correct stack as this appears to be a development question at least until you can identify if the problem is correctable through non-developement means.

Comment: The answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26375690/waiting-for-service-media-audio-policy-on-android-boot/43183347#43183347) might give you a clue. In that situation, the problem seemed to be caused by **libaudioflinger.so**.